# Add attribute to XML

Tags: xml, sed, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

XML to edit -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema">
  <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>
  <server configuration="file:/Users/gugu/Docs/artemis/var/lib/broker/etc//broker.xml"/>
  <web path="web" rootRedirectLocation="console">
    <binding uri="https://localhost:8161">
      <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
      <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
      <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
    </binding>
  </web>
</broker>
```

In the above XML, I want to add the below attribute `uri="https://localhost:8161"`.

```
keyStorePath="$path/server-keystore.jks" keyStorePassword="password"
```

After adding these, need to change `http` to `https` and also might need to change the port.

Result -

```
<binding uri="https://localhost:8443" keyStorePath="$path/server-keystore.jks" keyStorePassword="securepass">
```

The path and password used above for the `keystone.jks` should come from two different variables.

Can someone help me how to edit it in place using either XMLstarlet or sed command?

What I tried -
To add the attribute, (first I tried without variable)

```
xmlstarlet edit --inplace \
  --insert "/broker/web/binding[not(@keyStorePath)]" --type attr -n keyStorePath --value ".ssl/server-keystore.jks" \
  bootstrap.xml
```

There are no changes in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML file uses [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xml-namespaces/info) (`xmlns=`). This adds two attributes and updates one attribute:

```
xmlstarlet edit --inplace \
  -N x='http://activemq.apache.org/schema' \
  --insert '//x:broker/x:web/x:binding' --type attr -n 'keyStorePath' --value '$path/server-keystore.jks' \
  --insert '//x:broker/x:web/x:binding' --type attr -n 'keyStorePassword' --value 'password' \
  --update '//x:broker/x:web/x:binding/@uri' --value 'https://localhost:8443' \
  file.xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema">
  <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>
  <server configuration="file:/Users/gugu/Docs/artemis/var/lib/broker/etc//broker.xml"/>
  <web path="web" rootRedirectLocation="console">
    <binding uri="https://localhost:8443" keyStorePath="$path/server-keystore.jks" keyStorePassword="password">
      <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
      <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
      <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
    </binding>
  </web>
</broker>
```

Information about the syntax: `xmlstarlet edit`